# ASP.NET authorization using RestSharp

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, restsharp

On the site "example.net" I have standart api method to take access token (which i can call /Token) and if I make POST request using Fiddler to example.net/Token with parameters in request body[image: Using Fiddler] 
And all is OK. Status code 200 and in the response access token and other info.

But if I do this request from other site using RestSharp - 500 Internal Server Error. I tried to AddParameter, AddBody, AddObject. Make parameters as a JSON string, to change DataFormat, to AddHeader of Content-Type. This is my last version of request.

```
request = new RestRequest(URL, Method.POST);
//request.AddHeader("Content-Type", ContentType);
string UrlEncoded = "";
//I parse Parameters to format like I use in request body in Fiddler.
if (Parameters.Count != 0)
    foreach (var param in Parameters)
        UrlEncoded = param.ParamToUrlEncoded(UrlEncoded);
request.AddBody(UrlEncoded);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

Do i need to set any more attributes on the request or something?

Thank you.